# Moving Blocks Bootstrap in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to apply a moving block through bootstrap function in R. I am using daily SP500 return data from September 2008 to September 2018, inserting an arma (1,1) model to fit in the bootstrap procedure. This is the code:

`tsbootstrap(SP500.ret.core.vec, nb = 1000, arma, m = 5, b=22,
type="block",order = c(1, 1), coef = NULL, include.intercept = TRUE, 
series = NULL)`

I get the following error:

`Error in statistic(drop(y), ...) : 
  x is not a vector or univariate time series`

How to fix this?

Comment: There is not enough information about the data structure of `SP500.ret.core.vec` to answer your question. I suspect you have passed a data object containing the open, high, low, and closing prices, which is 4 vectors not a single one.

Comment: First of all thank you Justin. Sorry but in my question I forgot to  specify that SP500.ret.core.vec  is a ts numeric vector of SP500 daily log returns, computed from adj closing prices  downloaded through get.hist.quote. So it is a one column vector. Kindest regards.